# Is there any ADC chip that can be connected directly to the MCU's digital pins and so digital read can be done?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, adc

I am working on a project to read analog sensors. I need to read them and convert them to digital values and transmit them to the server and do the processing there. I need a ADC chip that can give out digital voltage or something that I can read through the GPIO of ESP8266 so that I can reject the MCU part in here. I cannot use the ESP's ADC pins as my input ADC voltage is little higher and also I don't want an extra circuit to be added in this. I just wanted to know if some chip like that is available that I can use it for my project. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in exactly the same position, the ADC of the ESP8266 is not ideal, since it will only allow values between 0v and 1v.

I havent been able to test it yet, but I found this page: https://github.com/rccursach/SAM_i2c_Dust_Sensor
In that tutorial they convert a analog value (in this case from a Sharp GP2Y1010AUF Dust Sensor) to a digital value with a ATTiny85, which can then be read over i2c. i2c is available on the ESP8266, so this seems like a proper solution.

Comment: there is no chip that I can connect to the ESP's GPIO directly without the i2c interface? Just curious if anything like that even exists. :P

Comment: if you're using a ESP-12 two if the ESP's pins are directly usable as I2c pins (the SDA and SCL pins, have a look here: http://domoticx.com/wp-content/uploads/esp8266-esp-12-module-pinout.png) 
So you can directly connect a ATTINY chip to the ESP